# Access to XMLHttpRequest at localhost:8080 from localhost:4200 has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: java, angular, spring, http, cors

*"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/authenticate/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."*

Spring Boot backend, Angular front. Tried sending an Http post, in the form of a login object containing a username and password. It's supposed to receive a jwt token in return. Works perfectly in postman, so it leads me to believe google chrome is the issue. I'm using the Allow CORS Chrome extention as well.

Weirdly enough the http GET requests work.

I tried making a proxy in angular which didn't fix the issue. I also might have done it wrong too, I'm new to making web applications so all the vague instructions on some websites really frustrate me.

**auth.service.ts** Which sends the request

```
import { Injectable, ɵCompiler_compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync__POST_R3__ } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {

    isAuthenticatedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
        const data = {
            username: username,
            password: password
        };
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set('Contact-Type', 'application/json'); 

        const url = `${environment.AUTH_ROUTE}`;
        return this.httpClient.post<any>(url, data, { headers: headers })
            .pipe(
                map(response => {
                    localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
                    this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(true);
                    return response;
                })
            );
        // { token: "vrijednost-tokena" }
    }

    logout() {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        this.isAuthenticatedSubject.next(null);
    }
}
```

**AuthController.java** Which receives the request

```
import com.example.stevan.madsapp.security.jwt.JwtTokenProvider;
import com.example.stevan.madsapp.web.dto.LoginDTO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping(value = "/login")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> login(@RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO)
    {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                loginDTO.getUsername(), loginDTO.getPassword()
        );
        try
        {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            String token = jwtTokenProvider.createToken(authentication);
            Map<String, String> responsePayload = new HashMap<>();
            responsePayload.put("token", token);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(responsePayload, HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Error while login", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm sorry in advance for my lack of basic knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` to the controller method should solve your issue. Take a look at [Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

Answer (score 0):

it is not solving for Delete request, but it works for put and the others, I added the cross origin as follows https://gyazo.com/e058904cb5ee27685fac4f3811b9b2a8
but getting this https://gyazo.com/7481236f8ed7fcdecd2c898227c90e08 while trying to delete the resource from angular app

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30694946)